# Crear Objeto con variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Saludos espero me ayuden, necesito relacionar un arreglos unidos en un objeto final,  mis arreglos a relacionar son los siguientes:

```
cabecera=['nombre', 'apellido'];
datos=['william', 'fernandez'];
```

necesito obtener un objeto que quede así:

```
obetoFinal={
   nombre:'william',
   apellido:'fernandez'
}
```

he intentado muchas cosas pero no logro obtener el resultado que necesito, hasta el momento he realizado esto pero me sale error 'Parsing error: Unexpected token ['.

```
cabecera.forEach((c, i)=>{
        let obj={
         cabeceras[i] :datos[i]
        }      
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltaba poco para lograr tu objetivo, solo hay que hacer algunas correcciones:

- El objeto se debe definir antes de ingresar en el ciclo, así como lo tienes, solo está disponible dentro
- Debes usar `obj['nuevaPropiedad'] = 'valor'`, porque, así como lo tienes, en cada iteración se sobrescribe el objeto completo y quedaría solo con la última propiedad.

```js
cabecera = ['nombre', 'apellido'];
datos = ['william', 'fernandez'];

// Inicializar objeto antes de entrar al ciclo
let obj = {};

cabecera.forEach((c, i) => {
    // "c" ya tiene el nombre de cabecera
    // "i" se usa como índice para obtener valor
    obj[c] = datos[i];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta es

```
obj = {};
obj[cabecera[0]] = datos[0];
obj[cabecera[1]] = datos[1];
```

Creamos un objeto vacío y luego creamos sus campos el nombre de cabecera y el valor de datos.

Para un caso más genérico, en el que pueda haber más de dos elementos

```
obj = {};

for(var i=0; i<cabecera.length; i++)
    obj[cabecera[i]] = datos[i];
```

Y ya, para asegurar que los datos son consistentes

```
obj = {};

if(cabecera.length == datos.length){
    for(var i=0; i<cabecera.length; i++)
        obj[cabecera[i]] = datos[i];
} else {
    // Manejar el error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 3 problemas

- Que crees que una variable declarada `let` o local vivirá cuando sale de la función pasada al `forEach`.
- Siempre sobre escribes esa variable.
- Si deseas agregarle más datos a tu array se te hará mas complejo, mejor usa un bucle `for` y usando al arreglo `datos` en vez del arreglo `cabecera`//Pues conoces cual es el tamaño del arreglo `cabecera` y no hay muchos elementos.

La solución es que declares la variable a fuera del `forEach` y que hagas:

```js
let output={};//Este será el objeto de salida.
let cabecera=['nombre', 'apellido'];
let datos=['william', 'fernandez'];

cabecera.forEarch( e => {output[e]=[];});//Esto es para poder almacenar arrays de los datos en su fila correspondiente.

for (let i=0,c_i=0;i<datos.length;i+=2,c_i++){
    output[cabecera[0]].push(datos[i]);//Insertamos el dato actual al final del array. cabecera[0]:[...]
    output[cabecera[1]].push(datos[i+1]);
}
```

Pero si deceas espandir el array `cabecera` para que no tengas que manipular el código puedes hacer otro bucle `for`.

```js
for (let i=0;i<datos.length;){//El aumento lo hará el otro bucle.
    for (let name in cabecera){
        output[name].push(datos[i]);//Asi rellenamos todas las filas de cabecera con los datos correspondiente.
        i++;
    }
}
```

Nota: Ninguno de las dos funciones es a prueba de errores, puede pasar que tengas menos `datos` que `cabecera` o viceversa.